# Find out which field matched term in custom score script

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

I am using a custom score query with a multiMatchQuery. Ultimately what I want is simple and requires little explaination. In my Java Custom Score Script, I want to be able to find out which field a result matched to.

Example:

If I search Starbucks and a result comes back with the name Starbucks then I want to be able to know that name.basic was the field that matched my query. If I search for coffee and starbucks comes back I want to be able to know that tags was the field that matched.

Is there anyway to do this?

Search Query Code:

```
def basicSearchableSearch(t: String, lat: Double, lon: Double, r: Double, z: Int, bb: BoundingBox, max: Int): SearchResponse = {
    val multiQuery = filteredQuery(
      multiMatchQuery(t)
        //Matches businesses and POIs
        .field("name.basic").operator(Operator.OR)
                .field("name.no_space")
                //Businesses only
        .field("tags").boost(6f), 
      geoBoundingBoxFilter("location")
        .bottomRight(bb.botRight.y,bb.botRight.x)
        .topLeft(bb.topLeft.y,bb.topLeft.x)
    )

    val customQuery = customScoreQuery(
      multiQuery
    )
    .script("customJavaScript")
    .lang("native")
    .param("lat",lat)
    .param("lon",lon)
    .param("zoom",z)

    global.Global.getClient().prepareSearch("searchable")
      .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
      .setQuery(customQuery)
      .setFrom(0).setSize(max)
      .execute()
      .actionGet();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only simple for simple queries. On complex queries, the question which field matched is actually quite nontrivial. So, I cannot think of any efficient way to do it.

Perhaps, you could consider moving your custom score calculation closer to the match. The [multi_match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query.html) query is basically a shortcut for a set of [match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query.html) queries on the same query string combined by a [dis_max](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/dis-max-query.html) query. So, you are currently building something like this:

```
custom_score(
    filtered(
        dis_max(match_1, match_2, match_3)
    )
)
```

What you can do is to move your custom_score under dis_max and build something like this:

```
filtered(
    dis_max(
        custom_score_1(match_1),
        custom_score_2(match_2),
        custom_score_3(match_3)
    )
)
```

Obviously, this will be a somewhat different query, since `dis_max` will operate on custom score instead of original score.